# To which package belongs the command \lorangebox?

Tags: packages

I need to copy some fancy formatted code listing from one documentation to another. The person who formatted the code back then used the command `\lorangebox` to highlight some parts of it. Now I am in search of the package `\lorangebox` belongs too, since I don't want to simple take over the whole header from the old documentation.

Does someone know, which package the command belongs too. Google unfortunately doesn't provide me with much information on this issue.

Comment: Since Google would be the predominant choice in finding this and you were unsuccessful, could you describe `\lorangebox` in a bit more detail? Even better, scan and post an image that shows the actual `\lorangebox` (even if you can't post images, post the link; someone with edit privileges will re-insert the image). Does it just have an `orange` line on the `l`eft, say? My bet is on [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) or [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I have not found it in TL 2011. Perhaps `\lorangebox` is directly defined in the
preamble. Have you searched the preamble?

If `\lorangebox` is defined somewhere else, then the package can be found by
looking at the definition of `\lorangebox` at different times:

1. Interactive: `\show\lorangebox` stops the LaTeX run and shows the definition.
   At the beginning it should be undefined, after `\begin{document}` it should contain
   something.
2. The meaning of `\lorangebox` can be written to the screen and `.log` file:

   ```
   \typeout{\string\lorangebox: \meaning\lorangebox}
   ```

   (`\string` just prints the following command and `\meaning` reveals the meaning.)
   That line can be added between the packages and studying the `.log` file should narrow the
   place, where `\lorangebox` is defined.

Comment: *headdesk* You are right. It was defined in the preamble. Thanks. Maybe there is a time, when I simply should stop working. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Looking for `\orangebox` instead (probably based on it) yielded me some clues:

Some file:

```
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage{tikz}


% \OrangeBox<overlay spec>[tikz picture/node options]{<content>}

% draws content boxed in an orange call-out box

\newcommand<>{**\OrangeBox**}[2][]{% \onslide#3{\NormalBox[fill=orange!30, draw=black!30,rounded corners=4pt,#1]{#2}}%
} 
.......
```

You should try the "**tikz**" and "**textpos**" packages for sure if they are within the original header.

Comment: Yep. It is based on that package. I would give you an upvote for this, but I can't do it yet. ;)

Comment: Thank you. Glad to help. Someone else then perhaps ^^?